# Prevent multiple service access same document in MongoDB till processing is done

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, microservices

I have multiple instances of a services. This service access a collection of unprocessed document. We are using MongoDB. The role of service is :

1. Fetch the first unprocessed document from collection A.
2. Make a Rest call using uuid.
3. Get the response and store the response in another collection B.

Multiple service may access the same document leading to duplicate. The steps which I can think to deal with this situation:

1. FindandModify() along with progress field. So we will call this function with query of progress field to be "0". We will update the value to 1 so other services can not access it. On getting the success from Rest call we can delete the record. On getting the failure we will again call the FindandModify() with update value to be "0" so other service can access  at later time.
2. We we call Find() function which will give us one document. We get the "_id" of the document and store it into another collection. If another service also gets the same document and that document "_id" is already present. Then it will not be insert again and that service again call Find() function.

What would be the performance and bottleneck of these approaches. Also do we have any other better approach which will enhance the performance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> FindandModify() along with progress field. So we will call this function with query of progress field to be "0". We will update the value to 1 so other services can not access it. On getting the success from Rest call we can delete the record. On getting the failure we will again call the FindandModify() with update value to be "0" so other service can access at later time.

This solution is OK and is simpler and faster than the second.

> We we call Find() function which will give us one document. We get the "_id" of the document and store it into another collection. If another service also gets the same document and that document "_id" is already present. Then it will not be insert again and that service again call Find() function.

This solution (as you presented) would not work unless the document is removed from the first collection after it is inserted in the second, otherwise the processes will be caught in an infinite loop. The drawback is that this solution implies two collections and the document moving process.

In any case, you must take into account the failure of the processes in any of the phases and you must be able to detect failure and recover from it.